# Applying blur filter to background, doesn't keep my div centered

Tags: html, css, sass

So I've got a blurred image div for my login on the web page im making.

Here is what it looks like so far:

[image: Problem..]

Now, the blurred part of the image is only supposed to be in the middle of the page with my dimensions as shown in the **SCSS** below:

```
//Variables
$background_image: url(../img/bg.png);
$background_fallback: #C0C0C0;

body {
    padding: 0; margin: 0;
    background-image: $background_image;
    background-position: 0px 0px;
    background-repeat: repeat;
    color: #333;

    animation: bg 40s linear infinite;

    min-height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}

.login_container {
    margin: auto;
    overflow: auto;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0; left: 0; bottom: 0; right: 0;
    width: 40%;
    height: 60%;

    .login_container_bg {
        position: fixed;
        left: 0; right: 0; z-index: 1;
        display: block;
        background-image: $background_image;
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;

        -webkit-filter: blur(2px);
        -moz-filter: blur(2px);
        -o-filter: blur(2px);
        -ms-filter: blur(2px);
        filter: blur(2px);
        animation: bg 40s linear infinite;
    }
    .login_container_inner {
        position: fixed;
        left: 0; right: 0;
        z-index: 2;
        margin-left: 20px; margin-right: 20px;
    }
}

@keyframes bg {
    from { background-position: 0 0; }
    to { background-position: 0 1000px; }
}
```

Here is the HTML structure I used:

```
<body>
    <div class="login_container">
        <div class="login_container_bg"></div>
        <div class="login_container_inner">
            Hello. It's me.
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

As you can see the blur part of the background spreads the width of the page. I want the blur bit to only be the width and height of the inner - which should be 50% and 50% (x, y) of the page

Comment: Your .login_container_inner is already centered.
Please give some more details what you expect.

Comment: @SebastianWiteczek As you can see the blur part of the background spreads the width of the page. I want the blur bit to only be the width and height of the inner - which should be 50% and 50% (x, y) of the page

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The position of the element is `fixed` to `left:0` of the viewport, not the container. - **fixed**  *The element is positioned relative to the browser window* http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_position.asp

Either change it to be positioned absolutely (relative to the container) or position it fixed relative to the viewport.

Edit: Try something like this.

HTML

```
    <div class="login_container_bg">
        <div class="login_container_inner">
            Hello. It's me.
        </div>
     </div>
```

CSS

```
.login_container {
margin: auto;
overflow: auto;
position: absolute;
top: 0; left: 0; bottom: 0; right: 0;
background-image: $background_image;

.login_container_bg {
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%; 
    top: 50%;
    transform:translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
    z-index: 1;
    display: block;
    width: 40%;
    height: 60%;

    -webkit-filter: blur(2px);
    -moz-filter: blur(2px);
    -o-filter: blur(2px);
    -ms-filter: blur(2px);
    filter: blur(2px);
    animation: bg 40s linear infinite;
}
.login_container_inner {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0; right: 0;
    z-index: 2;
    margin-left: 20px; margin-right: 20px;
}
}
```

Comment: Gavin, when I apply relative positioning to both bg and inner elements, they appear one ontop of another. http://i.imgur.com/4ctRRMk.png

Comment: I think you misunderstood my answer.

Comment: Oh so you meant to apply the absolute positioning to the inner elements as well as the top-level element? Okay that works perfect! Cheers

Comment: Gavin, your answer puts the blur over all the elements inside my inner as well

Comment: Well there's no other elements in your inner in the markup you provided. I can't work miracles.

Comment: Sorted it. Thanks for the help :)